# How to find area of parallelogram? which is defined by two vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, area

The parallelogram is defined by two vectors, $a$ and $b$ such that:
\begin{cases}
a=p+3q & \\
b=p-2q & \\
|p|=2 &\\
|q|=3 &\\
\angle (p,q)=\pi/3&
\end{cases}
 where $p$ and $q$ are also vectors.

Comment: Are you familiar with cross product?

Comment: Yes i know little about cross products but how do with these? |a||b|cos(a^b)

Answer (score 1):

Remember this:

> Area of a parallelogram defined by $2$ vectors $\vec p,\vec q$ as its two adjacent sides is$$\Delta=|\vec p\times\vec q|=|\vec p||\vec q||\sin\angle(p,q)|$$

Answer (score 0):

you can say $p = (2,0), q=(3 \cos \frac \pi 3, 3 \cos \frac \pi 3)$
find the coordinates of $a$ and $b$ and then look geometry of the shapes.

Or once you have $a , b$ apply the shoelace principle to $(0,0), a,b, a+b$

Or apply the shoelace principle to $(0,0), a,b$ and double it.

Or the area of the parallelogram  $= |det \begin{bmatrix} a_1&a_2\\b_1&b_2 \end{bmatrix}|$

and 
$\begin{bmatrix} a_1 & a_2 \\b_1 & b_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1&3\\1&-2 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} p_1 & p_2 \\q_1 & q_2 \end{bmatrix}\\
det\begin{bmatrix} 1&3\\1&-2 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} p_1 & p_2 \\q_1 & q_2 \end{bmatrix}= det \begin{bmatrix} 1&3\\1&-2 \end{bmatrix}det \begin{bmatrix} p_1 & p_2 \\q_1 & q_2 \end{bmatrix}$